# Access Outlook2003 from an application (Java) running on a Tomcat (started as a service)

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, outlook-2003

I want to exchange E-Mails from a locally installed Microsoft Outlook through a Java Application which is running on a Tomcat Server. 
In the past this was no Problem but since we switched the tomcat server from a "normal" starting routine to be started as a service (which is done for performance reasons) my Connection to Outlook is not working anymore.

As I was searching for a Solution to this quite for a long time (with no found solution) I decided to leave a post here.

I already know, that

> The Outlook Object Model is unsuitable to run in a Windows service

which can be found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237913. Due to the registry hive HKEY_CURRENT_USER which is not loaded when a service is started.

But in this case I think a simple 'No - that’s not possible' can’t be a solution and that’s why I am asking here for help.

- Is it for example possible to let the application on the tomcat start a new local application which then connects to Outlook?
- Is it possible to manually load the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive?
- or on the other hand do this by using a solution which I did not mention yet?

> Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: why do you need to go through outlook?  I think a cleaner design would be to talk to the mail server directly using SMTP and IMAP

Comment: @Rolf Rander thank you for your fast reply keeping the connection through outlook is necessary because a premise for the projekt was that the user can upload E-Mails that come with their outlook. In this case I can´t guarantee that every E-Mail a User wants to upload is also accessible via SMTP/IMAP. 
For example if a ouser confihurates his Outlook in that way, that all E-Mails are fetched and none of them are also stored online. Another aspekt would be if a user would like to upload a draft.

Comment: ah, ok.  I don't know that much about windows (or outlook), but probably a service is run outside of any user context (by definition), but to run outlook you need a user context (running an end-user application like outlook like a service probably doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to create a plugin to outlook which submits the email to your application using web-services (or similar).

I believe this is the usual way of realising requirements like this.

Comment: hi @Ralf thanks a lot in advance for your help. But I believe using an outlook plugin can't afford this because it also can not be reached by the application running on the server. :-(

Comment: I think you need outlook to contact the server, not the other way around.